# Mod_rewrite proxy reverse, serve content from another website

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I will try to explain you what I want to do:

I have my local website http://localhost/ (WAMP SERVER)
I have another website http://domain.com/

I would like to set a mod_rewrite rule maybe using proxyreverse so that all request to localhost are made to domain.com and served back from localhost without using any 301 redirect.

For exemple:
http://localhost/ should render the content of http://domain.com/
http://localhost/index.php?id=1 should render the content of http://domain.com/index.php?id=1

I would like if possible to pass also all the header, get and post.

I have tried this but with no success and can't find anything on google:

`ProxyPass / http://localhost/domain/
ProxyPassReverse / http://domain.com/`

I have also tried the tutorial from this link but it does redirect me to domain.com and that s not what I want http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/proxy.html

PS: mod_rewrite, mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http are activated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the P (Proxy) flag of mod-rewrite :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

This will internally forward all requests from your domain to example.com .

Comment: has this been changed? tried the code above to proxy `domain.com` to `api.domain.com` and it redirects me instead of forwarding it internally, thus changing the url

Comment: You need to add `SSLProxyEngine on` on top otherwise it will keep redirecting